# Woocommerce - Variable product shows Sold Out even if some Variations are In Stock

Tags: woocommerce, product

I am noticing a strange problem. The product shows "Sold Out" in the frontend, even if some Variations are In Stock. There are also Variations that have 0 stock.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure, you know that there is the option to manage stock separately for each variation of the variable product?

Comment: I have uploaded a photo so you can see what I upload exactly. I am doing it with an import CSV tool from Webtofee and have arount 30.000 products

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the problem was with merged cells that weren't so obvious in the excel. Also attributes needed to be case sensitive.